# How can I see the source of a webpage as it would be displayed on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, mobile, web

I don't have an iphone, but I want to see what the HTML looks like to my users using an iphone.

Is there a way to emulate an iphone, so that flash does not appear ?  For example if I visit YouTube, I don't want to see the Flash player in an emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download Xcode for free if you have a mac and you can use the iphone simulator bundled with it. See this link on [How to run iPhone emulator without opening Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379622/how-to-run-iphone-emulator-without-starting-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

try safari browser.  select **Develop**, **User Agent**, **iPhone** (or iPad or iPod Touch) from that menu.

if the **Developp** menu is not found then, **Show Develop menu in menu bar** in the **Advanced Preferences**