# How to launch .app through Terminal?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator, .app

For installing the .app file using Terminal I followed the steps provided here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/27313079](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535844/failed-to-attach-to-process-id-xcode) . 
It worked fine but when I try to launch, the application gets crashed. I followed few suggestions mentioned here [Failed to Attach to Process ID Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535844/failed-to-attach-to-process-id-xcode) but nothing worked for me so far. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, head over to Terminal, (assuming you have Xcode command line tools installed)

But first, launch iPhone Simulator.

Then type `xcrun simctl install booted /foo/bar.app` into the Terminal,
Where `/foo/bar.app` is of course, your app.
Then wait a couple seconds.

After it completes, head over to the app's `Info.plist` file and find the line that says `bundle identifier`. Next to it is the bundle identifier, which should look like this: `com.foo.bar` or the like.

Then go to Terminal again and type `xcrun simctl launch booted com.foo.bar`, Where `com.foo.bar` is your app identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
xcrun devicectl device process launch --device 0000xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  ai.yourapp.id --verbose
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.