# How do I run the Angular 14 SPA in Xcode

Tags: angular, xcode, web, single-page-application

I have an angular web application using version 14, I use visual studio code to run the application, but I wanted to run that in Xcode.

I tried using existing project by cloning from the repo, but I don’t see any of my typescripts files.,

Can someone help me how can I use the existing angular application in Xcode, run it in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run xCode in order to test your app on the emulator.

First you can go look at this question that some brilliant person (me) asked many years ago.
[How to run iPhone emulator WITHOUT starting Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379622/how-to-run-iphone-emulator-without-starting-xcode)

Most recent answer is:

Assuming you have Xcode installed in /Applications, then you can do this from the command line to start the iPhone Simulator:

```
$ open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

Then, just start the application as you would in VS code.

Once it is running, open the app in Safari on the emulator.